# Executing a href tag automatically coming from ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute an href tag call in an iframe but I am facing some issues, it is not working:

My server page is returning me code like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="iframe_a"></a>
```

Here is my success call back of ajax:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#contents').show().html("<iframe width='100%' height='90%' name='iframe_a'>" + eval(data) + "</iframe>");
}
```

But it does not work, I am not sure how to fix this, if any change is needed on the server part, I can change that, let me know thanks.

Issue #2:

After load I am using the following code to load the contents in a div:

```
$('#contents').show().html("<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id=hold_my_iframe><iframe width='100%' height='90%' name='iframe_a' src='" + data + "'></iframe></table>");
```

The above portion when I render my page in browser is coming like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="90%" src="//www.websitename.com " name="iframe_a">
complete page of the websitename.com inside
</iframe>
<table id="hold_my_iframe" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table>
```

The contents of the div box is like below:

```
<div style="display: block;overflow:auto;width:100%;height:auto;" class="tab default-tab" id="contents"></div>
```

I tried changing many things but first thing is it does not load the iframe in a table, I tried display: inline-block

**another thing is my iframe has a scroller of its own page inside, so my parent page iframe scroller does not work, it always pointing to its children scrollbars, how can i make that a fix**

Comment: Thanks Guys, I was able to make it up, but i am facing another issue:.I am updating my question

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question or are you going to expand one? In any case please don't forget to thank authors for their time if they helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `src` attribute of the iframe like this:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#contents').show().html("<iframe width='100%' height='90%' name='iframe_a' src='" + data.href + "'></iframe>");
}
```

Of course if I got your question right and the `data` argument contains a link object otherwise it might require some additional operations to derive a value of the `href` attribute.

**update 1:** One of those additional operations was specified by @WisdmLabs

**update 2:** You should render the iframe inside a table cell otherwise it's an invalid structure and a browser is trying to fix this bug for you. Here's how your code should look like:

```
$('#contents').show().html("<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id=hold_my_iframe><tr><td><iframe width='100%' height='90%' name='iframe_a' src='" + data + "'></iframe></td></tr></table>");
```

According to your scrollbar question please provide an example using a http://jsfiddle.net service or similar one.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
    $('#contents').show().html("<iframe width='100%' height='90%' name='iframe_a' src='" + $.parseHTML( data ) + "'></iframe>");
}
```

Use this instead directly putting href in src attribute in iframe tag